# SSRS Lookup a cell value from datasets using parameter condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, lookup

I have a dataset("users") generated from query which results in the data as follows which is displayed in a tablix in my report:

```
name salary
xyz 100
abc 200
pqr 150
```

Now, i have also a parameter for selecting the username.So, i just want to reuse this dataset to filter and display the salary in another textbox based on selected parameter.
e.g. If i select xyz from parameter , then the textbox value should be 100

I tried with this expression in my textbox

```
=Sum(Lookup(Fields!Name.Value,Parameters!Name.Value,Fields!Salary.Value,"Users"))
```

But, i get the error message as "The Value expression for the textbox2 uses an aggregate expression without a scope"

Comment: You cannot `Sum` what is returned from a `Lookup`. Remove the `Sum`, and your lookup will work, assuming that what is in the User dataset is already aggregated.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are passing arguments to the lookup function in a wrong order. Lookup function receives arguments in the below order:

```
=Lookup(
  the value to search,
  the field in which you are going to look for a match,
  the field you want to get,
  the scope
)
```

Your expression should look like this:

```
=Lookup(Parameters!Name.Value,Fields!Name.Value,Fields!Salary.Value,"Users")
```

[REFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx)

You can use `SUM` if the returned value is numeric but it could return a incorrect sum if you don't handle the null values returned when there is no a match.

```
=SUM(
  Lookup(Parameters!Name.Value,Fields!Name.Value,Fields!Salary.Value,"Users"),
  "Users"
)
```

Let me know if this helps.